# Cannot get Karma/Jasmine to work with my angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok. I have spent several hours trying in vain to get Karma to work with my Angular controller. Whatever I do, I get the following error. It seems that even if I remove the expectGET() calls, I still get the error; as soon as I call $http.flush();

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'totalBeforeDiscounts' of undefined
```

The code for my controller is as follows:

```
var quotePadControllers = angular.module('quotePadControllers', []);

quotePadControllers.controller('QuotesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function($scope, $http, $q){

var blankAddon;

// Setup initial state and default values
var ajaxGetAddOns = $http.get('/?ajax=dbase&where=aons'),
    ajaxGetFrames = $http.get('/?ajax=dbase&where=fcats');

$q.all([ajaxGetAddOns, ajaxGetFrames]).then(function(results){

    $scope.addons = results[0].data;
    $scope.frames = results[1].data;

    $scope.pairs = [
        {
            "frames" : angular.copy($scope.frames),
            "addons" : angular.copy($scope.addons),
        }
    ];
});

// Function for the 'add pair' button
$scope.addPair = function()
{

    $scope.pairs.push({
            "frames" : angular.copy($scope.frames),
            "addons" : angular.copy($scope.addons)
    });
};

// Function for the 'remove pair' button
$scope.removePair = function()
{
    if ( $scope.pairs.length > 1 ) 
    {
        $scope.pairs.pop();
    }
};


// Continually update the subtotal and total
$scope.$watch('pairs', function(pairs) {
    var totalBeforeDiscounts = 0; 
    angular.forEach(pairs, function(pair) {
        var subTotal = 0;
        angular.forEach(pair.addons, function(addon) {
            subTotal += addon.added ? addon.price : 0;
        });

        subTotal += pair.currentFrame !== undefined ? pair.currentFrame.price : 0;
        pair.subTotal = subTotal;
        totalBeforeDiscounts += subTotal;
    });
    pairs.totalBeforeDiscounts = totalBeforeDiscounts;
}, true);
}]);
```

and my test code:

```
describe('QuotesController', function()
{
beforeEach(module('quotePadApp'));

var ctrl, $scope, $http, frameCatsHandler, addOnsHandler, createController;


// Setup tests
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend, _$q_) {

    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $http = $httpBackend;

    frameCatsResponse = [{"id":145,"price":25,"brand":"mybrand"},
                         {"id":147,"price":45,"brand":"mybrand"},
                         {"id":148,"price":69,"brand":"mybrand"}]; 

    addOnsHandler = [{"id":1,"name":"addon1","price":30,"includeIn241":0,"description":null},
                     {"id":2,"name":"addon2","price":60,"includeIn241":0,"description":null}];              

    frameCatsHandler = $http.when('GET', '/?ajax=dbase&where=fcats').respond(frameCatsResponse);
    addOnsHandler = $http.when('GET', '/?ajax=dbase&where=aons').respond(addOnsHandler);

    createController = function()
    {
        return $controller('QuotesController', {'$scope' : $scope });
    };
}));

it('Should request frame cats and addons from the database', function()
{
    $http.expectGET('/?ajax=dbase&where=aons');
    $http.expectGET('/?ajax=dbase&where=fcats');
    createController();
    $http.flush();
});
});
```

Comment: You need to use "_ $httpBackend _" for the $http object.  There might be other things wrong as well.  Should also point out that doing http calls inside a controller is frowned upon.

Comment: Re: Using _$httpBackend_ I had gotten the impression that was to differentiate local variables of the same name and wasn't strictly essential.

Comment: Can you tell me why I shouldn't do HTTP calls inside a controller? Where should I do them instead?

Comment: This style guide explains the rational for keeping controllers slim and focused better than I can: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y035.  With respect to httpBackend, I don't have enough experience to know what will and will not work.  I just know that using the underscores work for me.  This post helped me get started:  https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/testing-angular-with-karma.  It does not have internal links but search for httpBackend for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have the following watch statement in your controller trying to set a `totalBeforeDiscounts` property on `$scope.pairs`.

```
$scope.$watch('pairs', function(pairs) {
    // ...
    pairs.totalBeforeDiscounts = totalBeforeDiscounts;
}, true);
```

In your tests, when you create the controller and then call `$http.flush()`, that's actually triggering a $digest cycle. This kicks off all watchers.

```
createController();
$http.flush();
```

The watch handler above will execute and since it executes before `$scope.pairs` has any value, the `pairs` argument passed into the watch handler is undefined, resulting in your error.

As per the documentation:

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization.
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Also, in the rest of your code you have `$scope.pairs` as an array, but in the watch you are trying to set a property like `totalBeforeDiscounts` on it. This doesn't look right.

Comment: Thanks for that! wrapping the inside of the watch with the comparison suggested in your documentation quote solved my problem!